# Spatial Transformer Networks vs Deformable Convolutions

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, computer-vision, convolution

As I understand **STN** as described by the the deepmind paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02025

- allow a neural network to learn how to perform spatial transformations on the input image in order to enhance the geometric invariance of the model.

whereas **Deformable Convolutions** https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.06211

- add 2D offsets to the regular grid sampling locations in the standard convolution.

From the paper:

*...deformable convolution does
not adopt a global parametric transformation and feature
warping. Instead, it samples the feature map in a local
and dense manner. To generate new feature maps, it has
a weighted summation step, which is absent in STN.*

To me STNs augment the input image whereas DC augment the kernel shape. Results should be similar/same in terms of field of view of the network? **Please correct me if mistaken.**

Answer (score 4):

The main difference, as they mentioned in the paper, is that STN has a global parameter to transform the features. That is, it computes **one** set of parameters to transform the input. DC computes a 2D offset map for each location in the input, so for each location in the input features there is a separate transformation.

Comment: The 2D offset map is fixed for an input layer, so I am not sure what you mean by 'for each location in the input'.

Comment: The offset map is learned via a convolution of the input feature map. 'For each location in the input' I am referring to each pixel has its own 2D offset. This is  illustrated in Figure 2 of the paper.

Comment: Right but the offset is shared throughout the input feature map. So let's assume a 25x25x50 input map with h x w x nbr features then the offset is the same for each pixel x 50. There was some confusion about this on medium/reddit.